# Custom validation not disabling the form submit button - angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I've created the reactive form in angular like below and my issue is that I want to disable the form submit button if passwords doesn't match.

**Form submit button code**

```
<button [disabled]="changePasswordForm.invalid">Change password</button>
```

**Reactive form code**

```
this.changePasswordForm = this.fb.group({
     oldPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
     newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
     newConfirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
}, {
     validator: this.passwordMatchValidator
});
```

**Password validator code**

```
passwordMatchValidator(AC: AbstractControl) {
    let newPassword = AC.get('newPassword').value;
    let newConfirmPassword = AC.get('newConfirmPassword').value;
    if (newPassword !== newConfirmPassword) {
      console.log("Passwords doesn't match.");
    } else {
      console.log("Passwords matched.");          
    }
 }
```

Until user enters the passwords of minimum length of 10 characters, the submit button of form is not getting enabled. But even if the passwords doesn't match, the form button is getting enabled. What logic I am missing here?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature is `passwordMatchValidator(AC: AbstractControl)` but you seem to bind your validator to your form.

Otherwise, you're not returning anything from your validator, how do you expect it to validate ? Try this.

```
passwordMatchValidator(AC: AbstractControl) {
  let newPassword = AC.get('newPassword').value;
  let newConfirmPassword = AC.get('newConfirmPassword').value;
  return { passwordMismatch: newPassword !== newConfirmPassword };
}
```

Comment: Hi trichetriche, you are correct, as I am not returning the password match status, form submit button is getting enabled. Thank you. Your solution is working.

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark your issue as resolved !